# Angular - How to perform a query only if a URL param exists

Tags: angular, url-parameters

I have the following query. Is it possible to only perform this if a URL param (paramOne) exists?

```
 queryAndSubscribe(){
    this._subscription = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      tap (params => {
        console.log('params = ', params);
      }),
      switchMap(params => {
        return this.service.getItems(params.paramOne);
      })
    ).subscribe(items => {
     // push to array
    });
}
```

I've tried putting an `if` statement within the switch map, but it produces an undefined streaming error.

Comment: put an if statement inside this.service.getItem() or inside the subscribe. If you want to terminate the process then there are other rxjs handlers available for that

Comment: Have you looked into Activated Route Snapshot ?
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Comment: just use `filter` operator. it should be easier than `if`

Comment: @Metabolic - doing that produces "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

Comment: I need to be able to listen to the route changes. Essentially the left side of the screen has items that when clicked on display items on the right. The items on the right are defined by the changing URL param (from the clicked item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use **filter** rxjs operator. In case the parameter is not provided the control will not pass to next operator in the pipeline.

Your code would get modified like this

```js
 queryAndSubscribe(){
    this._subscription = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      tap (params => {
        console.log('params = ', params);
      }),
      filter(params=>params.paramOne),
      switchMap(params => {
        return this.service.getItems(params.paramOne);
      })
    ).subscribe(items => {
     // push to array
    });
}
```